# Scheduled tasks not working for ColdFusion 11 when using https

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks

The scheduled tasks does not work in my environment for ColdFusion 11 when using https.  I have a simple test page that just sends an email hourly.  The exact same task works fine for http but not for https.  Even running the task manually from the CF11 Admin console, http works as expected https does not.  I am running CF11, apache-tomcat-7.0.56 and jdk1.7.0_45.

Any ideas?

Comment: If this is a scheduled task, could the CF file in question be put into a non browseable folder?  That would enable to use http.

Answer (score 2):

As you don't mention doing so, I am presuming you have not imported the SSL certificate. I googled "[ColdFusion 11 ssl certificate import](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp#q=coldfusion+11+ssl+certificate+import)" and this blog article has the most concise advice: "[Adding a certificate to the ColdFusion keystore](http://cfmasterblog.com/2008/11/09/adding-a-certificate-to-the-coldfusion-keystore/)". But the other results might help too.

They don't like just links being posted here, so in summary:

- Place the certificate on the ColdFusion server.
- Change to the directory {cf_installdirectory}/jre/lib/security
- Import the cert (keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias anyalias -file certificatefile)
- If the import is successful you will get a confirmation that the certificate was added to the keystore.
- Restart coldfusion.

(sorry for the plagiarism, Thought Asylum, but Stack Overflow has some fairly non-www-friendly rules we're made to work around).